# Writing data from JavaDStream<String> in Apache spark to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am working on programming to process data from Apache kafka to elasticsearch. For that purpose I am using Apache Spark. I have gone through many link but unable to find example to write data from JavaDStream in Apache spark to elasticsearch.

Below is sample code of spark which gets data from kafka and prints it.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import scala.Tuple2;

import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Durations;
import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

import java.util.List;
public class SparkStream {

    public static JavaSparkContext sc;
    public static List<Map<String, ?>> alldocs;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        if(args.length != 2)
        {
            System.out.println("SparkStream <broker1-host:port,broker2-host:port><topic1,topic2,...>");

            System.exit(1);
        }

        Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        SparkConf sparkConf=new SparkConf().setAppName("Data Streaming");
        sparkConf.setMaster("local[2]");
        sparkConf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true");
        sparkConf.set("es.nodes","localhost");
        sparkConf.set("es.port","9200");
        JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(2));

        Set<String> topicsSet=new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(args[1].split(",")));
        Map<String,String> kafkaParams=new HashMap<>();
        String brokers=args[0];
        kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list",brokers);
        kafkaParams.put("auto.offset.reset", "largest");
        kafkaParams.put("offsets.storage", "zookeeper");
        JavaPairDStream<String, String> messages=KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                jssc,
                String.class,
                String.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                StringDecoder.class,
                kafkaParams,
                topicsSet
        );
        JavaDStream<String> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
              return tuple2._2();
            }
        });
        lines.print();
       jssc.start();
       jssc.awaitTermination();
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

One method to save to elastic search is using the `saveToEs` method inside a `foreachRDD` function.  Any other method you wish to use would still require the `foreachRDD` call to your dstream.

For example:

```
lines.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.saveToEs("ESresource"))
```

[See here for more](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/master/spark.html)

Comment: I am not getting syntax for java.

Comment: The syntax above is for pyspark.  For Java try `import org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark; JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, "ESresource"); `

Answer (score 0):

```
 dstream.foreachRDD{rdd=>
        val es = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF("use headings suitable for your dataset")
        import org.elasticsearch.spark.sql._
        es.saveToEs("wordcount/testing")
  es.show()
}
```

In this code block "dstream" is the data stream which observe data from server like kafka. Inside brackets of "toDF()" you have to use headings. In "saveToES()" you have use elasticsearch index. Before this you have create SQLContext.

```
val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
```

If you are using kafka to send data you have to add dependency mentioned below

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.2.1"
```

[Get the dependency](http://%20https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients)

[To see full example see](https://github.com/ashanchameera/kafka-spark-elasticsearch.git)

In this example first you have to create kafka producer "test" then start elasticsearch
After run the program. You can see full sbt and code using above url.